# Forcing jaxb2-maven-plugin to generate setters or constructors

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb, xjc

I have a following build configuration. It is working properly, however the problem is in case of generating constructor with all args or generating setters for list.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/resources/xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Can you tell me how to force `xjc` to generate setters for lists or args-constructors ?

Comment: Maybe first using a more recent version of jaxb2-maven-plugin and based on the documentations use [enableIntrospection](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/xjc-mojo.html#enableIntrospection) in the plugin configuration....BTW: Why changing the outputDirectory default of the plugin? Keep convention over configuration...

Comment: It doesn't help. Setters for lists are not generated.

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

This thing works for me

```
<configuration>
    <args>
        <arg>-Xvalue-constructor</arg>
    </args>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
           <artifactId>jaxb2-value-constructor</artifactId>
           <version>3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</configuration>
```

Let me know if you find any issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

For generating setter for the collection I added the dependency to **org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons** but it' works only for the new version of **jaxb2-maven-plugin**. I tried with **2.5.0** and it's works, using the version **2.3.1** doesn't work.
Here an example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>collection-setter-injector</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <executions>
      <execution>
             ......
       </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
       <sources>
             ......
       </sources>
       <arguments>-Xcollection-setter-injector</arguments>
       <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
       <extension>true</extension>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate collection setters you have to add **collection-setter-injector** to jaxb plugin dependencies and for value constuctor generation - **jaxb2-value-constructor**. You also have to add proper args to argument list (**-Xcollection-setter-injector** and **-Xvalue-constructor**. Example plugin configuration in pom.xml:

```
...
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>collection-setter-injector</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-value-constructor</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    ...
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        ...
                    </sources>
                    <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-Xcollection-setter-injector</argument>
                        <argument>-Xvalue-constructor</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

Comment: But this throws error for me:

[WARNING] Error injecting: org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.XjcMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
1) [Guice/ErrorInjectingConstructor]: Error: ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.runtime.package-info
at XjcMojo.<init>(XjcMojo.java:58)
while locating XjcMojo
Learn more:  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ERROR_INJECTING_CONSTRUCTOR
1 error
Full classname legend:
======================
XjcMojo: "org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.XjcMojo"
End of classname legend: